# How to get each item from a filtered array, without using a map for each item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm taking an array and filtering the value in a context:

```
const { responsible } = useResponsible()
const [ids, setIds] = useState([])

const filteredResponsible = responsible?.filter((resp) =>
    ids.includes(resp.id)
  )
```

The problem is that I need to make a map to get the corresponding value of each id, one by one. This ends up making the code too long:

```
 const { filteredResponsible } =  useResponsible

 const responsibleName =  filteredResponsible.map((resp) => resp.name)

 const responsibleEmail =  filteredResponsible.map((resp) => resp.email)

 const responsibleAddress =  filteredResponsible.map((resp) => resp.address)
     ...

And so on with each item in the array.
```

I'm using the React Hook Form's setValue to set the value in the inputs:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setValue('name', `${responsibleName}`)
    setValue('email', `${responsibleEmail}`)
    setValue('address', `${responsibleAddress}`)
    setValue('cep', `${responsibleCep}`)
    setValue('district', `${responsibleDistrict}`)
    setValue('city', `${responsibleCity}`)
    setValue('state', `${responsibleState}`)
    setValue('phone', `${responsiblePhone}`)
    setValue('sex', `${responsibleSex}`)
  }, [])
```

How can I make these maps smaller? Without having to make a map to get each item in the array?

Comment: Is it intentional that you rely on the implicit `join` when doing (for instance) `setValue('name', `${responsibleName}`)`? (Since `responsibleName` is an array with potentially multiple elements.)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to do those `map` calls on every render and to do them anywhere other than where you need them, since you only show using the result in a mount-only effect. Just do them there:

```
const { filteredResponsible } = useResponsible; // Is there really no `()` needed here?

useEffect(() => {
    setValue("name", `${filteredResponsible.map(({name}) => name)}`);
    setValue("email", `${filteredResponsible.map(({email}) => email)}`);
    setValue("address", `${filteredResponsible.map(({address}) => address)}`);
    // ...
}, []);
```

If you really need those distinct arrays on every render, unless you can change your data structures to be more amenable to your output I don't see you have a lot of options. You can at least avoid multiple loops through `filteredResponsible`:

```
const { filteredResponsible } =  useResponsible; // ()?

const responsibleName = [];
const responsibleEmail = [];
const responsibleAddress = [];

for (const { name, email, address } of filteredResponsible) {
    responsibleName.push(name);
    responsibleEmail.push(email);
    responsibleAddress.push(address);
}
```

And if that's really the case, you may want to avoid doing it on every render:

```
const { filteredResponsible } = useResponsible; // ()?

const { responsibleName, responsibleEmail, responsibleAddress } = useMemo(() => {
    const responsibleName = [];
    const responsibleEmail = [];
    const responsibleAddress = [];
    for (const { name, email, address } of filteredResponsible) {
        responsibleName.push(name);
        responsibleEmail.push(email);
        responsibleAddress.push(address);
    }
    return { responsibleName, responsibleEmail, responsibleAddress };
}, [filteredResponsible]);
```